# d3 Node Labels and collapsing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a D3 that displays a force directed network and will collapse its children on click. I would like to to also display the names of the nodes on hover. Something like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1212215

Below is my code so far.

```
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Added markers to indicate that this is a directed graph
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 4)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("test.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  //Give nodes ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = root.nodes[i];
    node.id = i;
    node.collapsing = 0;
    node.collapsed = false;
  }
  //Give links ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.links.length; i++) {
    var link = root.links[i];
    link.source = root.nodes[link.source];
    link.target = root.nodes[link.target];
    link.id = i;
  }
  // for (var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++){
  //   var node = root.nodes[i];

  // }
  update();
});

function update() {
  //Keep only the visible nodes
  var nodes = root.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });
  var links = root.links;
  //Keep only the visible links
  links = root.links.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })


  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d){ return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d.collapsed ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
    root.links.forEach(function(l) {
      if(l.source.id == d.id) {
        if(d.collapsed){
          l.target.collapsing--;
        } else {
          l.target.collapsing++;
        }
      }
    });
    d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
  }
  update();
}

</script>
```

My issue is with the update function. I was able to get it to display, but when I clicked to collapse, it wouldn't show the labels after. Im not sure if I should be tweeting the tick or what.

thanks!

Comment: can you also post test.json

Comment: The json file readme.json from the link will work with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the circle and text labels using SVG group element as shown below.

```
var groupNodes = node.enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; }); 
     .on("click", click)
     .on("mouseover", function(){ 
         d3.select(this).select("text").style("display","block"); 
     })
     .on("mouseout", function(){ 
         d3.select(this).select("text").style("display","none"); 
     })
     .call(force.drag);

groupNodes.append("circle")                
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color);

var label = groupNodes.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("display", "none)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; //Use the key which holds the name value });
```

The above code replaces following part of the code in the update function.

```
 node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
```

and now change the tick function as follows

```
function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; 
  });
}
```

Now all other functionalities should work as expected.

Comment: I am having some issues incorporating this into my code. Where exactly does the first block go? I am getting uses with the nodes and node.enter variables

Comment: The first block should be written inside the update function. This code will create nodes as groups which will contain each circle and corresponding text elements

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now the names will display statically. Is there an easy way to change it to display on hover? Or perhaps I should ask on a new thread.

Comment: Updated in the answer. Hope it helps. Please accept helpful answers.